# Testing the existence of helm element defined in values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am new in helm and currently come up with a situation where I need to test the existence of 2 parameters defined in values.yaml and if present, use the value of the same in sample.yaml.

Note - This is sure that one of them will be present.

For example:

I am testing for these 2 values:

```
1 - {{ .Values.probes.xyz.readiness.initialDelaySeconds }}
2 - {{ .Values.readiness.xyz.initialDelaySeconds }}
```

And inside sample.yaml, I have to implement one of the above parameter based on existence:

```
initialDelaySeconds: <one of the above values needs to be implemented based on the existence>
```

I understand it's a simple `if else` condition, but I am unable to implement.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For logic where you want to use some value if it's set and some other value if not, the Helm [`default`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#logic-and-flow-control-functions) function is usually a good match.

```yaml
{{- $v1 := .Values.probes.xyz.readiness.initialDelaySeconds }}
{{- $v2 := .Values.readiness.xyz.initialDelaySeconds }}
initialDelaySeconds: {{ $v1 | default $v2 }}
```

If you have multiple settings like this, you can also do things like [`merge`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#merge-mustmerge) the two values-item dictionaries together.

```yaml
{{- $readiness := merge dict .Values.probes.xyz.readiness .Values.readiness.xyz }}
initialDelaySeconds: {{ $readiness.initialDelaySeconds }}
```

Comment: I suppose, with my case, 2nd option will work just fine. Thank you David!

Answer (score 0):

```
{{- if .Values.probes.xyz.readiness.initialDelaySeconds }}
initialDelaySeconds: {{ .Values.probes.xyz.readiness.initialDelaySeconds }}
{{ else if .Values.readiness.xyz.initialDelaySeconds }}
initialDelaySeconds: {{ .Values.readiness.xyz.initialDelaySeconds }}
{{- end }}
```

> > [helm Flow control](https://docs.helm.sh/zh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/)